# How to submit form using PhantomJS and wait for the next page

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, form-submit

I have a simple tornado app here.

```py
class TestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        print "here ~!"
        self.render("test.html")

    def post(self):
        action = self.get_argument("add")
        print "action : ", action
        self.write(action)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/test", TestHandler),
    ])
    application.listen(8126)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

then here is the "test.html".

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/test" method="post" id="aaa">
        <input type="text" id="add" name="add" value="add">
        <button id="go" onclick="submit();">go</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and finally the phantomjs script:

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('http://host-ip/test', function() {
    page.evaluate(function() {
        document.getElementById("aaa").submit();
    });
    phantom.exit();
});
```

when I run the script, I got "here ~!" in my tornado-app, but no more output. meanwhile, I open 'http://host-ip/test' and click the button, then I got both "here ~!" and "action : add" in my tornado-app's output.

BTW, I also tried jQuery in PhantomJS script to click the button, but still only get "here ~!", no "action : add"...

Comment: You're exiting too early.

Comment: "setTimeout " just help~ many thanks :-)